# load video by an URL with html5 javaScript WITHOUT Jquery

Tags: html5-video

I work on videos, I use JavaScript, Html and canvas.My problem is; I have to give for the users the possibility to add a URL and load the video of the URL and add it on the canvas,and to give an effect for this videon, for this reasons that i used cancas, I have a problem with my function on JavaScipt, i have a message error when i put an URL, i don't know where is the problem.

I'm sorry for my English

```
           <!HTML>
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                <meta charset=utf-8 />
                <script src="video.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                <title>Video streaming</title>

                <h1> <marquee>Streaming </marquee></h1>
                <center>
                    <h1> Choisir video </h1>
              <!select another Local video> 
                  <select onChange="javascript:loadAnotherVideo(this.value);">
                      <option class="item" value="video2.MP4"> 1er Video</option>
                      <option class="item" value="IMAG0008.MP4">2eme video</option>
                      <option class="item" value=" video.webm">3eme video</option>

                    </select>
                    <! Select another video by URL>
                       <p>
                <form id='ui'>
                  <fieldset>
                    <input id='url' name='url' type='text' placeholder="C:\Users\PC MC\Desktop\projetMPA\video2.MP4">

                    <button id='syn' type='button'>Soummetre</button><br>
                    <label>Chemin de votre Video:</label><br>
                    <output id='view'></output>

                  </fieldset>

                </form>

                       </p>

                    <h1> Choisir effet </h1>

                <!choose effect>
                <span id="cvsModeLbl">Mode:</span>

                <input type="button"  id="cvsbtnNormal" value="Normal"  onclick="myFunction();"/>
                <input type="button"  id="cvsbtnBW" value="Black &amp; White" onclick="myFunction1();"/>


                <!myvideo>
                <h1> Vidéo Side by side</h1>
                <video crossOrigin="anonymous" id='v'  controls loop width="500" height="400">

                  <source src=video2.mp4 type=video/mp4>
                    <source src=video2.webm type=video/webm>
                    <source src=video2.ogg type=video/ogg>

                </video>


                <canvas id=c width="500" height= "400"></canvas>

                    </center>   



                <script>


                // fonction video LOcal
                 function loadAnotherVideo(src) {
                    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
                    var sources = video.getElementsByTagName('source');
                    sources[0].src = src;

                    video.width="600";
                    video.height="500"

                    document.getElementById('c').width = video.width;
                    video.load();
                }


                //fonction URL
                var UI = document.forms.ui;
                // Set click event on form--have it run init() when clicked
                UI.addEventListener('click', init, false);


                function init(e) {

                var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
                  // Reference all fom controls of #ui
                  var ui = e.currentTarget.elements;
                  // Get the value of #url
                  var url = ui.url.value || null; 

                  // afficher mon lien en dessous
                  ui.view.innerHTML = url;

                    var vid = document.querySelector('#v');
                    // Set its src to value of url
                    vid.src = url;

                    // load video tag
                    vid.load();
                  }



                // recupération de la donnée video
                    var v = document.getElementById('v');
                //recupération du canvas
                    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
                //creation du context du canvas
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    var back = document.createElement('canvas');
                    var backcontext = back.getContext('2d');

                    var cw,ch;

                        cw = v.width;
                        ch = v.height;
                        back.width=cw;
                        back.hight=ch;
                        back1.width=cw;
                        back1.height=ch;
                        console.info('canvas.width', cw);
                        console.info('canvas.width', back.width);





                 // fonction normal
                 function myFunction(){
                   context.clearRect(0,0,500,400);
                    // First, draw it into the backing canvas
                    context.drawImage(v,0,0,cw,ch);


                  //setTimeout(function(){ myFunction() }, 10);
                  requestAnimationFrame(myFunction);    

                }

                //fonction noir et blanc
                 function myFunction1(){

                  context.clearRect(0,0,500,400);
                    context.drawImage(v,0,0,cw,ch);
                    // Grab the pixel data from the backing canvas
                    var idata = context.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch);
                    var data = idata.data;
                    // Loop through the pixels, turning them grayscale
                        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=4)
                        {
                            var r = data[i],
                                g = data[i+1],
                                b = data[i+2],
                                gray = (r+g+b)/3;
                            data[i] = gray;
                            data[i+1] = gray;
                            data[i+2] = gray;
                        }

                    idata.data = data;
                    // Draw the pixels onto the visible canvas
                    context.putImageData(idata,0,0);



                    // Start over!
                    //setTimeout(function(){  myFunction1(); }, 10);

                        requestAnimationFrame(myFunction1); 
                        }
                }
```

Comment: "without Jquery if it's possible. " of course it is! jQuery creators had to write it without jQuery... :D

Comment: what is `videl` variable?

Comment: i'm sorry it's not videl but "video"

Comment: You can run a video locally, but you can't run canvas locally it will be *"tainted"*, you need to upload everything to a server (or a local server should suffice but not entirely sure...) I believe this applies to your situation:https://simonsarris.com/understanding-the-html5-canvas-image-security-rules/

Answer (score 1):

## Update

I found the source of code you have copied from and here's a blockquote from said [**article**](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1804854&seqNum=6):

> *"If you’re creating this example as you follow along, it won’t work unless you run it through a web server. A local file will be considered “cross-origin” (i.e., from another website), so the API will forbid you from obtaining an image from it and manipulating its pixels. This cross-origin security policy exists to prevent files on one domain from accessing and altering information from a file on another domain without permission."*

So as I had already explained, you must upload to server and keep the webpage and video on the same requirements as [**Same Origin Policy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy):

- **Protocol:** **http://** or **https://**<sup>✸</sup>
- **Host Sub-domain:** `http://`**www.**
- **Host Domain:** `http://www.`**example.com**
- **Port:** `http://www.example.com`**:80**<sup>✸</sup>

  ---

  The JavaScript for `<canvas>` wasn't included so no guarantees that this answer will work. As long as you add this code carefully with the canvas it will work, but if it doesn't work with your canvas, please do not just say *'it doesn't work'* (because it does work in this demo). Add the JavaScript that runs canvas and I'll help you get it running.

### References

[**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)

[**Event.currentTarget**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

[**Event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

[**Event Delegation**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

**Details commented in Demo**

### Demo

```js
// Reference the form
var UI = document.forms.ui;
// Set click event on form--have it run init() when clicked
UI.addEventListener('click', init, false);


function init(e) {
  // Reference all fom controls of #ui
  var ui = e.currentTarget.elements;
  // Get the value of #url
  var url = ui.url.value || null;
  // Display value of #url in #view
  ui.view.innerHTML = url;
  // Run vidSync() passing value of url
  return vidSync(url);
}


function vidSync(url) {
  // Quit if value of url is null
  if (url === null) {
    return false;
    // Otherwise...
  } else {
    // Reference the video tag
    var vid = document.querySelector('#vid');
    // Set its src to value of url
    vid.src = url;
    // load video tag
    vid.load();
  }
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  max-width: 450px
}

input,
output {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
  font: inherit
}
```

```html
<form id='ui'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your Video</legend>
    <input id='url' name='url' type='text' value='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4'>

    <button id='syn' type='button'>SYNC</button><br>
    <label>Link of your video:</label><br>
    <output id='view'></output>

  </fieldset>
  <video id='vid' controls></video>

</form>
```

Although Event Delegation isn't  necessary in this particular code I used the methodology in case of expansion (i.e. more form controls in the future).

There is a way to **[bypass this requirement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin)**

<sup>✸</sup>It's enforced only if it's explicitly included. Excluding these particular requirements is an easy bypass.

Comment: hi, it's exactly what i search, but i don't know how i can integrate the video into the canvas, I already did it but for local videos and it's not the same things!

Comment: The canvas isn't necessary to run the video unless you want to run some type of special function on it. The practice of canvas and video is not common nor is it practical. Why do you need canvas?

Comment: BTW I've tested OP code with a functional url and it doesn't work so naturally I would assume that is the problem not canvas. How could I help you with canvas if you haven't provided sufficient code that involves canvas. I have requested your code that runs canvas. What you have now isn't even close to canvas.

Comment: I work on stereoscopic videos, I have to give the user the possibility to take a video SIDE by SIDE and to be able to visualize it (side by side or anaglyph) I used canvas to be able to apply functions on the videos, the last thing that i have to do is give users the ability to retrieve a link from a video side by side and make the desired effects, for theses reasons that i have to put my video on the canvas

Comment: If you render video in canvas side-by-side then there should be no problem because canvas depends on the video tag playing a video. The video tag depends on the src url to play a video. Canvas has nothing to do with getting a url to a video. If I'm mistaken then post the code for canvas. 1. Canvas is specialized so it's impossible fix it, modify it, let alone understand it without the code. 2. Canvas needs the video for the side-by-side. My code presents a video when a url in inputted by user.

Comment: exactly what I was saying, so adding your code should work perfectly, but I have a problem I can not understand because I can not get the video there is an error message

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere. I noticed the url placed in the placeholder attribute in OP code. Is that the intended site that the videos are coming from? `https://ubotube.univ-brest.fr/videostream/` and what's the error logged as specifically?

Comment: i will edit my publication and i will put all my code to explain you where is the probleme

Comment: thank you, I'm really happy to found someone to help me and explain what was wrong, finally it was not a problem with the canvas

Comment: please, you don't know how i can upload a video directly on my server, i don't think that it's possible, no?

Comment: If you don't know how would I know? It depends on what is available to you personally or on a business level. Just by that question alone I can see that you need a grasp of basic concepts.The possibilities on how to approach the subject is staggering. If you have a server, you need to know what it's capable of, what you are able to do with and how to do whatever with your server.