# Fetch videos from my personal google drive and display on website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-drive-api, google-picker

I want to use google drive as a video hosting platform.

I have a website where I offer a video course. I would like to use the videos I stored in my google drive, fetch them and display them on my website using React.

I have had a problem finding the correct info in the google dev documentation.

Do I knee to use google drive API or google picker API?

Can I solve this issue using only the front end? When reading the google drive API docs it seems you need to use node.js as well?

Comment: You might be looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930558/load-video-by-an-url-with-html5-javascript-without-jquery

Comment: The post is about displaying videos but I don’t see the connection to google drive?

Comment: You just need to give URL of your video, It can be hosted on any server, even on google drive. Make sure that it's a direct URL to download the video.

Comment: Ahh okey, I see. I will check that out

Comment: Google drive API would help you for sure.

Answer (score -3):

I found a solution here:

[Streaming a video from Google Drive using HTML5 video tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880756/streaming-a-video-from-google-drive-using-html5-video-tag/52397246#52397246)

Basically, this is what you do.

1. **Get the shareable link of your video**. This can be done by right-clicking
   the video in Google Drive and clicking the get shareable link button. Copy
   this link to your clipboard.
2. **View the video with the shareable link**. Just paste the link you obtained from the previous step into your web browser. Please use either Firefox or Chrome for the next few steps.
3. **Select the quality you want.** Use the Google Drive player and select your desired quality like 1080p or 720p. Click play to make sure the quality changed.
4. **Get the absolute path of the video.** Here's the fun part: right-click on the video player and you will see the built-in menu with options like loop and stats for nerds. Right-click again and you will see the browser built-in menu with options like copy video address or save video. Select copy video address and to test it out, paste it in a new tab and see if the video plays.

Comment: Please don't just copy-paste content from another answer. Instead, vote/flag to close the question as a duplicate.